# How to make carousel message in GiftedChat React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

Here is what I want to do

[Message Carousel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Otu.jpg)

I can make a message with buttons, but I don't know how to combine components in order to create a carousel.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. Basically you just need to modify your `renderBubble`. I passed some props to tell that the message received is a carousel.

I used `ScrollView` for my outer container and `View` for each block.

```
<ScrollView  style={{
     backgroundColor:'white', 
     height: 200, 
}} horizontal={true}> 
    <View> <View/>
</ScrollView>
```

and for normal text just return `Bubble`

```
<Bubble {...props} />
```